# Load knockout components dynamically

Tags: knockout.js

This is my html :

```
<a href="#page1">page 1</a>
<a href="#page2">page 2</a>
```

This is my js :

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function ($, ko) {


     ko.components.register('page1', {
    require: 'App/Controllers/page1'
});
ko.components.register('page2', {
    require: 'App/Controllers/page2'
});

    window.onhashchange = function () {
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
        $('#body').html('<' + hash + '></' + hash + '>'); //hash = page1 or page2
    }

    ko.applyBindings();
})
```

However, when hash changes, components doesn't load and body content is simply:
 `<page1></page1>` or second page.  If i would change my js like this :

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function ($, ko) {

    ko.components.register('page1', {
    require: 'App/Controllers/page1'
});
ko.components.register('page2', {
    require: 'App/Controllers/page2'
});

    $('#body').html('<page1></page1>');

    ko.applyBindings();
})
```

It works fine

Comment: You have to realize that Knockout will only take arbitrary changes to the DOM into account when calling `applyBindings()`. You can try to call `ko.cleanNode(document.body)` then `ko.applyBindings()` on `hashchange` event though.

Comment: Can you explain me what is the best way to arcitecture large single page application, based on hash change?

Comment: You should have a viewmodel that's aware of which page it should currently be displaying, and have the hashchange event update some state in that viewmodel.  Generally modifying the DOM manually in such a large scale manner is inconsistent with using knockout.

Comment: Well, Knockout doesn't seem to bother itself with routing like Angular does. But try things like http://pagerjs.com/ and more.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sammy.js but Pager.js is more Knockout oriented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing the body html is going to leave everything unbound. You should not use `cleanNode`; it is a kludge.

If you want to change which component is being used, use the [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) on the containing tag (`body` is fine), using an observable that contains the desired component. Here's an example, using a timer to change the template.

```js
ko.components.register('page1', {
    template:'page1 template'
});
ko.components.register('page2', {
    template:'page2 template'
});
 
vm = {page:ko.observable('page1')};
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function () {
    vm.page('page2');
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component: page"></div>
```